Thread Problem in Build Pipeline (Reactor + Micronaut)
I get following Exception in one of my tests when Running in Bitbucket Pipeline (locally runs fine):
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe#park
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:754)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:990)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:322)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.CancellableMonoSink.tryEmitValue(CancellableMonoSink.java:91)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.ConnectionManager$Pool$ConnectionHolder.emitPoolHandle(ConnectionManager.java:1360)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.ConnectionManager$Pool$Http1ConnectionHolder.dispatch0(ConnectionManager.java:1519)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.ConnectionManager$Pool$ConnectionHolder.lambda$dispatch$3(ConnectionManager.java:1388)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this Problem?
I tried to enable thread pooling but it did not fix it:
micronaut:
  http:
    pool:
      enabled: true

